# How to filtering mutation with boolean if isVerified === true user can signin

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql

**Hello how can i filtering and find only isverified === true user can signin?
And if it false user can't signin in mutation**.

My code on mutation

```
signin: async (
    _: any,
    { credentials }: SignInArgs,
    { db }: Context
  ): Promise<UserPayloadType> => {
    const { email, password } = credentials;

    // compare input form email with data in database avaliable or not
    const user = await db.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        email,
      },
    });

    if (!user) {
      return {
        userErrors: [
          {
            message: "There was a problem with your login",
          },
        ],

        token: null,
      };
    }
```

```
mutation : activationAccount(emailAccount: String): ActivationAccountPayload!
query: 
type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    name: String!
    isVerified: Boolean!
    #this is will updating on db in every signup
    email: String
    image: String
    # likes: [LikedPost]!
    posts(take: Int!, skip: Int!): [Post!]!
    profession: [Profession!]!
  }
```

any help i appreciate it. Please help me :")

Answer (score 0):

This is a litle problem hehe, yesterday was not focusing what i do.

So in user.findmany that you find the user and then

just call user.isverified === boolean and adding a if statement and it working fine.